# PHP trying to simply a repetitive script involving rowsets

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to simplify a repetitive script that I'm doing in PHP. I've looked at a few loop options but since it involves rowsets being returned from a MySQL stored procedure it's not acting properly. I'm doing this same script about 15 times to return all the data. Ultimately I'm looking to pass back a json_encode array to the ajax calling it. The results I keep getting when trying to put it in a loop is a 500 error or a poorly constructed array.

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $values = array();
    
    $stmt->execute();
    $values = array();
    $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
    
    if ($rowCount > 0) {
       $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
       
       $values = array();
       
       foreach ($row as $rowvalue) {
           $values[] = array($rowvalue[0], $rowvalue[1], $rowvalue[2], $rowvalue[3], $rowvalue[4], $rowvalue[5]);
       }
       
       $stmt -> nextRowset();
       $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
       
       foreach ($row as $rowvalue) {
           $values[] = array($rowvalue[0], $rowvalue[1], $rowvalue[2], $rowvalue[3], $rowvalue[4], $rowvalue[5]);
       }
       
       $stmt -> nextRowset();
       $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
       
       foreach ($row as $rowvalue) {
           $values[] = array($rowvalue[0], $rowvalue[1], $rowvalue[2], $rowvalue[3], $rowvalue[4], $rowvalue[5]);
       }
       ...
       echo json_encode($values);
    }
```

Updated to use the code example below:

```
    $sql = 'CALL fo_SELECT_Operations_Detail(?,?,?)';
    $facility = $_POST['facility'];
    $startweek = $_POST['startweek'];
    $endweek = $_POST['endweek'];
    
    $sql->bindParam(1, $facility, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $startweek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(3, $endweek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    
    $values = array();
    
    do {
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        foreach ($rows as $r) {
           $values[] = array($r[0], $r[1], $r[2], $r[3], $r[4], $r[5]);
       }
    
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
    
    // all processed so now send JSON
    echo json_encode($values);
```

Comment: Yep and it does work perfectly, till you try to put it in a json_encode and pass back to ajax then it fails.

Comment: Ok, so what if any messages are in the Error log on or near the 500 error line

Comment: The stored procedure works as expected. It returns the results and I'm able to individually move to each row set without issues. It's just when it's put into a loop that it breaks down.

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to say was the original script I posted works. However, in order to successfully get all results I'm having to call a rowset, iterate through it, exit that section call the next rowset, iterate through it and so on. It means I'm going to have duplicated code 15+ times. When I make the same call but using your example it's not executing. The stored procedure is returning correctly though. Working on the error code now, unfortunately editing in cpanel and can't easily get to the ini file so trying to figure out how to echo errors.

Comment: There shoudl be a PHP Error log, sometimes it is amalgamated with the Apache error log

Comment: @RiggsFolly it seems have a problem with the PDOStatement fetchAll(). From the error that I could retrieve. Causing a fatal error STLSTATE[HY000] Stack Trace: PDOStatement-&gt;fetchAll(3)  thrown on that line calling the fetchall. Is there another way to retrieve when in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We all forget that SP's which create rowsets also create an annoying empty one as well that has to be Next'd over, but not actually unloaded. The `&& $stmt->columnCount()` looks after getting `nextRowset()` called but not actually attempting to process it in any way.

```
$sql = 'CALL fo_SELECT_Operations_Detail(?,?,?)';
$stmt->prepare($sql);
    
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['facility'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['startweek'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['endweek'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt = $conn->execute();

$values = array();

do {
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
       $values[] = [$r[0], $r[1], $r[2], $r[3], $r[4], $r[5]];
   }

} while ($stmt->nextRowset()  && $stmt->columnCount());

// all processed so now send JSON
echo json_encode($values);
```

Comment: Thanks, that results in a 500 error though. I updated my example above to incorporate your example.